# ER diagram help,

Tags: entity-relationship

If I have an entity such as "Job" that has an attribute called "type" that specifies what type of job it would be, How would I add a relationship from it, to an entity such as "Recipient List" where the "Recipient List" is only applicable when "type" equals "delivery". What would this look like?